# D3js how do you draw a circle exactly at the middle of a doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I wanted to create a doughnut chart with d3.js and I want to put a navigation button just exactly on the middle of it, maybe when clicked shrinks the whole chart into a smaller version (expand probably). But that is not how complex my question is, but if you can find an example that probably exactly what I wanted to have, its better.

The question now is just position a `circle`, I don't know if there is a better alternative for it, but this is how it goes.

```
var height=800,
    width=800;

var data = [10,50,80];

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["red", "blue", "yellow"]);

// the graph
var radius=300;

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var group = canvas.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(300,300)");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(100)
    .outerRadius(radius);
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d){
       return d;
    });

var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");

arcs.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", function(d){
       return color(d.data);
    });

canvas.append("g")
      .attr("class", "collapse")
      .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 100)
        .attr("cy", 100)
        .attr("r", 100);
```

I just a did a dirty append of circle, because I don't want to go on, if there is a better way to do it, that is why I asked. How would one make it to the center, and if you are to generous, how to add events on it, probably using `on`, and then scale it down to about `100px` and make it the button itself, so when toggled again, it *collapses*

#### EDIT

Guess I'm a bit asking to much, how about:

Center the button without hard coding `300px` to it? and on your opinion , would an svg circle can do fine as a button?

Comment: You seem to be asking about 5 different things, all of which are covered by at least one of the many tutorials and examples on the D3 website. As for your code, it looks ok to me, apart from the fact that the center of the circle would be at 300,300.

Comment: yeah, got really excited when I typed the question, i'll edit it, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Why you want to use svg to make circle shaped button in the first place?

Comment: To answer your question: you've hardcoded the 300px translation of the group element, so you'll have to hardcode it for the circle as well :) And I don't see a reason to not use it as a button.

Comment: guess that's my bad asking after all.